# CoreData is it possible to safely use NSManagedObject from one context/thread in another context/background task

Tags: swift, core-data

Is it possible to use NSManagedObjects between different background Task?
I have such code that when executed loads NSManagedObjects using load() method on one context/background task using inside .performBackgroundTask { context

Then I want to execute another .performBackgroundTask { context but the problem is that NSManagedObject seems to be there unavailable as all properties starting from .performBackgroundTask { stop returning fields

```
 self.load(predicate: NSPredicate(format: "company.id = %@", companyId))
            .flatMap { contacts in

                Future { promise in

                    self.storage.persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { context in

                        let request : NSFetchRequest<Company> = Company.fetchRequest()
                        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", companyId)

                        let result = try? context.fetch(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read [Core Data concurrency overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html) to understand the basics. 
Regardless of your problem...
You can't directly pass Managed Objects between contexts/threads. 
What you can do is to pass [objectIDs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1506848-objectid) off objects from one context and use them to fetch the objects from another context/thread. 
Performance-wise it might not be a good idea if there are many objects and I recommend you to fetch both contracts and companies in one `performBackgroundTask`, using a single context. You may pass the context as a parameter to your `load` function if you don't want to expose its logic.

Comment: Ok I go this way and repeated fetch logic just in each method instead of reusing it. Maybe I could improve my Dao with having one private context instead of performBackgroundTask, but this duplication isn't so long and bad. on UI I use FetchRequest from SwiftUI now it seems to work much better.

Comment: Instead of copying the fetching you can make a method which will have context as a parameter and will return the array of results. Glad that I could help :)